# How to Access Multiple Fields of JSON data with the same call? (Ajax/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Good Morning,

I'm trying to make an Ajax/jQuery call to more than one data field within some nested JSONP data from a gaming website API (World of Warcraft).

The following works fine when I set the data field to "professions" or "items" (and comment out the opposite one in the myCallback function)... the HTML table will show the answer.  But it won't do it with both.

In this particular example, it tells me that the "primary" attribute can't be found because "professions" is undefined.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Wreckedified Raiding</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myCallback(data) {
            //$("#iLevelE").html(data.items.averageItemLevelEquipped);
            //$("#prof1").html(data.professions.primary[0].name);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                "url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/Eldershield?jsonp=myCallback",
                "type":"GET",
                "data": { fields: "items"},
                //also tried { fields: ["professions", "items"]},
                //a single data set works with { fields: "items"}
                "dataType":"jsonp",
                "contentType":"application/json",
                "jsonpCallback":"myCallback",
                "success":function(data){
                    console.log(data.items);
                    //console.log(eldershield.professions);

                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="prof1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="iLevelE">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
```

I read another stackoverflow question similar to this, and an answer suggested nesting the ajax calls within each other, as in, putting one inside the "success" trigger of the previous.  But I was under the impression that it was possible to append multiple data sets into one by utilizing the "data" tag in the call.

For clarity, I'm looking to have access to all the data in the "items" and "professions" data so that both statements in the myCallback function work.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `fields: "professions", fields: "items"` that is making one overwrite the other you probably want it to be an array with both in it: `fields:["professions","items"]`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Evans.  I'll check it out when I get home.

Comment: umm nope not a teacher lol

Comment: Yea, sorry, edited out the post right away, that was Joseph Evans, not Patrick :)

Comment: While Dreamweaver agrees that the syntax is correct, it's still not working.  In fact, I can't even get a console printout of either items, nor professions.  It works if I just go back to a single field in the data block.

Comment: then battle.net's api may only allow to get one field of data at a time, you will have to consult their documentation on how to form a proper request.